# Why am I unable to call this function? Discord.py and ASYNC/AWAIT issues

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot friends but am having trouble in calling this function dice_roll(). When I don't await it, I get this error: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'dice_roll' was never awaited
However, after adding "await" and trying to use the command, it never runs at all. I've read a bunch of documentation and tried several things, but I'm just not familiar enough with async/await to know what I'm really doing. I have another command which works fine aka "ich liebe.." in which the bot replies "die Kuche!"

Code is below

```
import random
import discord 
import asyncio

bot = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def dice_roll():
    try:
        dice_type = int(input())
        await message.channel.send("Roll which dice: ")
        num_dice = int(input())
        await message.channel.send("How many times: ")
    except ValueError:
        await message.channel.send("Please use an integer like '4' or '20'.")
        await dice_roll()
    output = []
    for i in range(num_dice):
        rolls = random.randint(1,dice_type) 
        output.append(rolls)
        formatted_output = str(output)[1:-1]
    await message.channel.send("You rolled {}".format(formatted_output))
    print("Task result: Dice was {} and num times was ()".format(dice_type, num_dice))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "rolling":
        dice_roll()
    elif message.content == "ich liebe":
        await message.channel.send("die Kuche!")
        print("cake command complete")
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is ready!")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: It runs if you await it... But you're waiting for an input in the command prompt...

Comment: `dice_type = int(input())` it waits for the input in the terminal of the application, you can use `bot.wait_for(...)` instead, here are the docs related to it : [bot.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Answer (score 0):

You have set the function to:

```
@bot.event
async def dice_roll():
```

But you want:

```
@bot.command()
async def dice_roll():
```

Because event is when an event happens such as

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
```

And a command is like a function, which is callable

Answer (score 0):

I made it work

```
import random
import discord 
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def dice_roll(message):
    try:
        await message.channel.send("Roll which dice: ")
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message')
        dice_type = int(msg.content)
        await message.channel.send("How many times: ")
        msg2 = await bot.wait_for('message')
        num_dice = int(msg2.content)
    except ValueError:
        await message.channel.send("Please use an integer like '4' or '20'.")
        await dice_roll(message)
    output = []
    for i in range(num_dice):
        rolls = random.randint(1,dice_type) 
        output.append(rolls)
        formatted_output = str(output)[1:-1]
    await message.channel.send("You rolled {}".format(formatted_output))
    print("Task result: Dice was {} and num times was {}".format(dice_type, num_dice))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "rolling":
        await dice_roll(message)
        print("dice rolled successfully")
    elif message.content == "ich liebe":
        await message.channel.send("der Kuchen!")
        print("cake command complete")
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is ready!")
       
bot.run(TOKEN)
```